# How can I embed scrollView on top of UIViewController's view and add custom UIView which has content inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Here are some code that i am doing to achieve that view

```
 let height = view.bounds.size.height * 2
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.frame)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    scrollView.addSubview(topView)
    scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(topView)
    topView.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, leading: scrollView.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: scrollView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 500))

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
```

top view is UIView anchor() method is the custom method that use NSConstraints to anchor objects

Comment: Please add some context and the question text to the body of your question here. What have you tried so far? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: By this code it is visible to know that I want to add topView into scrollView and when i scroll content of the scrollView should scroll. Unfortunately, topView is not showing up and scroll is not working, but when i remove topView from scrollView, it is scrolling but no content inside

Comment: Perhaps provide some kind of concept drawing of the UX could help, it's really hard to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have UICollectionViewCell, and when cell is tapped I am presenting UIViewController's view using animate() method, not controller itself, then when view is presented. I have imageView and collectionView inside and it does not fit the height of all my objects. So that's why, I want to use scrollView to scroll down to show more content in the UIController's view. and . i have 2 UIView which are top and bottom but when i embedding the scrollView to the UIViewCOntroller's view it is working, then when i adding my custom UIViews it is not scrolling even

Answer (score 0):

first thing is UIscrollview is also like a UIview which scrolls.so you can have most the properties accessible.